# No lintable files found at paths SwiftLint

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftlint

I tried to install SwiftLint using CocoaPods and I add in Build phases the following script :

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/SwiftLint/swiftlint"
```

SwiftLint is installed correctly and I get many errors and warnings in the project.

Then, I create the swiftLint.yml file in which I modify some rules but they are not token into consideration and the same number of errors and warnings persist in Xcode project.

When I run this command to confirm the application of the rules :

```
    ./swiftlint lint --config .swiftlint.yml
```

I get the error :

```
 No lintable files found at paths : ''
```

How can I solve this issue please?

Comment: I didn't get that error when running the same command on my rules file so I assume the error is inside the `.swiftlint.yml` file

Comment: Could you please show you .swiftlint.yml file?

Answer (score 13):

It happens also if you rename the directory of your app, make sure you report the change in the .swiftlint.yml too at first lines :

```
 included: # paths to include during linting
    - My_App_Directory
```

Comment: That was my problem. The default .swiftlint.yml file includes only the "Sources" folder. They should warn people about that on the Readme.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you do not need to add explicitly the`--config` file if the `yml` file is in the running directory (from where you are running the command) and name is `.swiftlint.yml`.

Secondly, you need to specify the path for your source with `--path`. Below command will work fine in your case,

```
swiftlint lint --path SourcePath
```

Answer (score 3):

If you installed it using Cocoapods this can help you.
I will just merely improve the above answers, to put clarity on how to resolve the issue of SwiftLint not finding the path.

Things to lookout for.

- Make sure your swiftlint.yml file is valid.
- Make sure the swiftlint.yml is in the same level as your .xcodeproj
- Don't specify --path and also add an entry under included: inside your yml file, choose one, either specify the --path or add an entry don't use both otherwise SwiftLint will ignore the --path param, and if the entry specified inside included: is wrong you will get the "no lintable file found" error

In your script.

- The gihub page of SwiftLint recommends just using "${PODS_ROOT}/SwiftLint/swiftlint" but that didn't work for me, I had to specify the --path see below for the full script.

> "${PODS_ROOT}/SwiftLint/swiftlint" --path "${SRCROOT}/Classes" --config "directory-of-your-config"

The --path param should be your own `--path "${SRCROOT}/Classes"`

[image]

Finally inside the yml file.

Make sure your included and excluded file specification is correct, see how I did mine below.

```
included:
  - Your-Project-Name
  
excluded:
  - Pods
```

One Important thing to note is if you add directories under included: the --path param will be ignored, and you might possibly get the "no lintable files found" error if the directory is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

For those of you who used 0.42.0 before and updated to 0.43.0 (or higher?).
They made a change and now interpret `included` and `excluded` as relative paths.

> Configuration files now consistently have their included/excluded
> relative file paths applied relative to their location in the file
> system. Previously the root configuration file applied these relative
> to the current working directory, but nested configurations applied
> these to their location in the file system.

From the release notes of [0.43.0: Clothes Line Interface](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/releases/tag/0.43.0).

Comment: So what should I add inside the `.yml` file for the `included` and `excluded`. I simply excluded one of my `.swift` files because I didn't want that to be linted,  and didn't added any `included` because I wanted to lint a particular commit file only.

Comment: Use it as usual but keep in mind that they have changed how these paths/filenames are applied. I've added the appropriate part as quote to my answer.
E.g. if your `.yml` lays in _myRoot/aFolderName/mySwiftLint.yml_ and you want to exclude a file in _myRoot/aDifferntFolder/myFile.swift_ then you have to add `../aDifferentFolder/myFile.swift` to your `exclude`.

Answer (score 2):

- if you are using swiftLint with CocoaPods : try `"${PODS_ROOT}/SwiftLint/swiftlint" --config .swiflint.yml` in your SwiftLint Run Script in your project build phases.
- make sure your .swiflint.yml config file is in the root of your project directory ( beside .xcodeproj file ).
- make sure the paths included on your .swiflint.yml (in included: and excluded: sections ) is valid paths
- make sure your .swiflint.yml file is valid yaml
- don't escape the directory paths in your config file
  dont do :  `- some\ Directory`but do  `- some Directory` without escape character.

Comment: I tried it like `--config .swiflint.yml` and it didn't work, but the below answer did: 
`--config "${PROJECT_DIR}/.swiftlint.yml"` (Xcode 12.1)

Answer (score 1):

For swiftlint from version 0.41 the following code worked for me in the build phase (workspace with several projects. Depending on the project configuration, it may be that "../" has to be removed from the path information):

```
cd ${PROJECT_DIR}/../
"${PODS_ROOT}/SwiftLint/swiftlint" --config "${PROJECT_DIR}/../.swiftlint.yml"
```

Here is a screenshot of the build phase entry:

[image: Build Phase Entry for swiftlint via cocoapods]

Comment: not working, my .yml file is at root path

Answer (score 1):

Replace `autocorrect` with `--fix`

```
export PATH="$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin"

if which swiftlint > /dev/null; then
  swiftlint --fix && swiftlint
else
  echo "warning: SwiftLint not installed, download from https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint"
fi
```

Comment: This is only adding a warning

Comment: What is the warning? If something like `it compiles every time..` uncheck the `based analysis..` condition in the run script

Comment: that's correct. autocorrect option is now replaced with --fix

Answer (score 0):

For M1, don't go for swift lint installation VIA PODS instead use Brew.
For installation run below command in Terminal

```
brew install swiftlint
```

and add below scripts into RunScript into build phase of your target.

```
export PATH="$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin"
if which swiftlint > /dev/null; then
  swiftlint
else
  echo "warning: SwiftLint not installed, download from https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint"
fi
```

Comment: No word about why this should solve the issue.

Answer (score -2):

```
If you using pod file then follow this steps:

Run Script: "${PODS_ROOT}/SwiftLint/swiftlint"
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: dragging won't help

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me

```
if which "${PODS_ROOT}/SwiftLint/swiftlint" >/dev/null; then
    ${PODS_ROOT}/SwiftLint/swiftlint --fix && ${PODS_ROOT}/SwiftLint/swiftlint
else
    echo "warning: SwiftLint not installed, download from https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint"
fi
```

Comment: This will add a warning only, where is the solution?